# How to display a success message upon redirection from controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, laravel, laravel-blade

In my application I have a form that validates and inserts records into the table.

Upon successful insertion into the table the controller `redirect()`s back to the page ass follows:

```
return redirect('/');
```

This works fine, except for the fact that it doesn't tell the user of whether the insertion took place at all or not as only the blank form remains on the page while no success message is displayed.

How can I redirect along with data (some form of `return code`) so that I can display a simple success message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```php
return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Message sent!');
```

Read more about [redirects in Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects).

Be sure that Session is working properly to get flash message working.

Comment: I'm new to Laravel. What am I supposed to do with Session?

Comment: You might find using `Session::push` useful if you want to push multiple messages to the redirect page. Just remember to do a `Session::pull` on the redirect page to ensure that the messages are removed from the session. See [Session](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session) for more information.

Comment: @ikartik90 nothing by default :)

Comment: Are these session values `name, value` pairs?

Comment: To display the message to the user, use: 
    `@if(Session::has('message'))
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{Session::get('message')}}
      </div>
    @endif`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```

and `@include('flash-message')` used this where you want to show your flash message on your page. thanks